# api call timeout vs api call attempt timeout dynamodb

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, dynamodb-queries

I have been trying to understand the difference between `apicallattempttimeout` and `apicalltimeout`. What I could understand is `apicalltimeout` is the total time till the client request waits for the response before giving up whereas `apicallattemptimeout` includes timeout for retries as well in addition to the time in the first attempt.

So does this mean that `apicallattemptimeout` will always be **more** than `apicalltimeout`? Example : Suppose I keep `apicalltimeout` to be `1000ms` and for a single retry I want the timeout to be `300ms`. So values will be for `apicalltimeout= 1000ms` and `apicallattemptimeout= 1300ms` ? API docs dont seem to help here
[apicallattempttimeout](https://sdk.amazonaws.com/java/api/latest/software/amazon/awssdk/core/client/config/ClientOverrideConfiguration.Builder.html#apiCallAttemptTimeout(java.time.Duration)) and [apicalltimeout](https://sdk.amazonaws.com/java/api/latest/software/amazon/awssdk/core/client/config/ClientOverrideConfiguration.Builder.html#apiCallTimeout(java.time.Duration))

Comment: My reading of the docs suggests that `apiCallTimeout` should be greater than `apiCallAttemptTimeout` because the former includes retries. Whether it *must* be greater is a different question. The SDK may allow you to set any relative values and it will simply timeout whichever is exceeded first.

Comment: @jarmod i think the later includes retries.

Comment: The [apiCallTimeout](https://sdk.amazonaws.com/java/api/latest/software/amazon/awssdk/core/client/config/ClientOverrideConfiguration.Builder.html#apiCallTimeout(java.time.Duration)) documentation indicates "This includes request handler execution, all HTTP requests including retries, unmarshalling, etc".